# Displaying an error message from a4j:jsFunction

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have this `a4j:jsFunction` below and an `<h:message for="form" style="color:red" />` somewhere else on the page.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <a4j:jsFunction id="createEvent" name="createEvent" immediate="true"
        action="#{calendarController.createEvent()}"
        data="#{calendarController}"
        oncomplete="renderEvent(event.data.eventId, event.data.eventTitle)">
        <a4j:param name="eventTitle"
            assignTo="#{calendarController.eventTitle}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</h:form>
```

How do I add an error message produced in `calendarController.createEvent()`?

Tried it with `context.addMessage("form", new FacesMessage(e.getMessage()));` but it doesn't work. I get this error: `WARNING: There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.`

Answer (score 1):

With `a4j:jsFunction` you are just performing an Ajax call; the view is not refreshed and the other components will continue in their previous state.

Use the `reRender` attribute to force refreshing the `h:message` component.

Comment: So I extendet the `h:message` with an id: `<h:messages id="messageForm" for="createEvent" style="color:red" />` and added a `reRender="messageForm"` to the `a4j:jsFunction`. I also tried different possibilities, e.g. `reRender` the elemnt wrapped arround the `h:message`. But I got nothing to work. What do I have to reRender?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue recently. I was using `h:commandButton`:

```
        <h:commandButton id="buttonOK"
                         onclick = "#{rich:component('purchasePopup')}.hide(); finishPurchase();"
                         value="Ok"
                         styleClass="popupPrimary"
                         rendered="#{validationSeverity != 'ERROR'}"
                         type="button">
        </h:commandButton>
```

I also had jsFunction which would be called on button click and call backing bean method. Backing bean was adding FacesMessages using addMessage method:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="finishPurchase" action="finish" render="purchaseForm"/>
```

Solution was to add `render="purchaseForm"` because all tags were nested in this form.